# Maybe don´t reuse cell in collectionView?

Tags: ios, ios7, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Hi have a problem in my recent project.

I have a **UICollectionView** with a list of different type of cells.
Recently i needed to add a new type of cell which have a very complex structure(e.g a UICollectionView inside).
When the app reuse this type of cell i have a little glitch (i need to reset the subviews, constraints, colors).

Due that, the app will have better fell if i don't reuse this kind of cells. I know when this happen, probably i have a problem with my implementation design. However, did you know any kind of solution to set one type of cell inside a UICollectionview to don't reuse?

Any suggestions and advices are welcomed

Answer (score 0):

Not reusing cells won't solve your problem. It would just change when it occurs. If you have some complex calculations, you may choose to calculate them only once or calculate them when needed. First approach delays your initial loading time, on the other hand second approach seems like a glitch while scrolling. But still, if you don't fix the over-calculation problem, it's not a real solution.

For the first approach you can define an array of UICollectionViewCells and fill it on -viewDidLoad method. So, you have all the cells pre-initialized, and now you can use them on UICollectionViewDataSource methods without having performance problems.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @DenizAdalar but my cells are all from different type soo i can t make something like "define an array of UICollectionViewCells and fill it on -viewDidLoad method". Sometimes i have only one a kind of cell represented in my structure. Since the recreating have a complex calculations my confer was to don t reuse that kind of cell